# Sign in and scrape search results on LinkedIn using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, linkedin-api

Sorry for this stupid question but I am so new to programming and have a deadline to meet for my thesis. I greatly appreciate your patience and help!

My goal is to get data from LinkedIn. One possible way I just knew (from youtube videos) is to search on google then scrape links for further scraping.

```
import mechanize
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0')]
br.set_handle_robots(False)
html = br.open('http://google.com/search?q=site:linkedin.com%2Fjob%2F+big+data')
html = html.read().lower()

#let handle the unicode character
html = unicode(html,errors='ignore')

#raw result
#print html

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
#print soup
```

In the soup I see this portion that contains the link that I wanna scrape.

```
<div data-async-context="query:site%3Alinkedin.com%2Fjob%2F%20big%20data" id="ires">
...    
<a href="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;q=&amp;esrc=s&amp;source=web&amp;cd=5&amp;cad=rja&amp;uact=8&amp;ved=0CGIQFjAE&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fjob%2Fgoogle%2Fbig-data-jobs%2F&amp;ei=U9TsU8mECZOkyQSLxoCYAg&amp;usg=AFQjCNGlr9VqOU8WSGS_8eJpVqWpKM3rIQ&amp;sig2=lFrE7FgtzqS4dfSD-k_cKA&amp;bvm=bv.72938740,d.aWw" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','5','AFQjCNGlr9VqOU8WSGS_8eJpVqWpKM3rIQ','lFrE7FgtzqS4dfSD-k_cKA','0CGIQFjAE','','',event)" wrc_done="true" data-href="https://www.linkedin.com/job/google/big-data-jobs/"><em>Big Data</em> Jobs at Google | LinkedIn</a>
...
</div>
```

The link that I want is "https://www.linkedin.com/job/google/big-data-jobs/"

However, I don't know why my following code does not work. Can someone advice?

```
for google_body in soup.findAll('div',attrs={'data-async-context':"query:site%3Alinkedin.com%2Fjob%2F%20big%20data"}):
    for google_links in google_body.findAll('a'):
        print google_links.get('data-href')
```

Comment: Easiest way is to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library to pull pages and send requests (like logging in), then use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse each page's html.

Comment: @cpburnz When I commented he didn't have any code, just asked the question in general. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25311251/revisions

Comment: @cpburnz Doesn't really matter, just wanted to show I wasn't crazy. Actually you responding showed me his updated question, and I'm glad OP was able to follow up with code, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When viewing in the browser, I see `<div id="ires" data-async-context="...">`, but when using Python to download it I only see `<div id="ires">`. It looks me like all of the `data-async-*` attributes are added with Javascript. However, I think you can get what you want by changing your loop slightly.

```
import urlparse

for google_body in soup.findAll(id='ires'):
    for google_links in google_body.findAll('a'):
        # *href* looks something like:
        #   /url?q=https://www.linkedin.com/job/big-data-jobs/&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=6ejsU4ipGYGBygTnpICIAw&amp;ved=0CCwQFjAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNG_JhHqlpkvZ4DSgABsqaRt-hR6uA
        href = google_links.get('href')

        # Parse the query arguments out from *href*.
        # *args* will look something like:
        #   q=https://www.linkedin.com/job/big-data-jobs/&sa=U&ei=6ejsU4ipGYGBygTnpICIAw&ved=0CCwQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNG_JhHqlpkvZ4DSgABsqaRt-hR6uA
        # and then:
        #   {'q': ['https://www.linkedin.com/job/big-data-jobs/'], 'usg': ['AFQjCNG_JhHqlpkvZ4DSgABsqaRt-hR6uA'], 'sa': ['U'], 'ei': ['6ejsU4ipGYGBygTnpICIAw'], 'ved': ['0CCwQFjAA']}
        args = urlparse.urlparse(href).query
        args = urlparse.parse_qs(args)
        url = args['q'][0]
        print url # https://www.linkedin.com/job/big-data-jobs/
```

For reference, I downloaded the page using:

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://google.com/search?q=site:linkedin.com%2Fjob%2F+big+data', headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
html = resp.read()
```